# How can i add auto counter to model objects?

Tags: python, django, admin

I had 4 objects but when i deleted one, i shown based on object id not actual numbers of objects ?

Model objects

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBbCV.png

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing there is unique identifiers for the objects, ie. primary keys. They cannot change even if you delete one from the middle of the list. This is so that database knows which row some ForeignKey points to.

What you should do actually is to use `MyStudent.objects.count()` to get the count of the objects, if that is what you want to display.

If you need to have row number on the table on user interface then that information should not be stored on database. Instead you should do something like this:

```
{% for student in my_student_list %}
    {{ forloop.counter }} # starting index 1
    {{ forloop.counter0 }} # starting index 0

    # Print what ever you want here..
{% endfor %}
```

So Django already provides you `forloop.counter` and `forloop.counter0` helpers that you can use for that.

For more information about buildin templatetags you should read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for

As you seem to be using Django Admin to show your data, maybe this post will help you to add row numbers there: [How to add a line number to each row of a tabularinline block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412602/how-to-add-a-line-number-to-each-row-of-a-tabularinline-block)

Comment: i found a way you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

add a function to count

at models.py

```
        def add_counter(myModel):
              objects = myModel.objects.all()
              index = 1
              for obj in objects:
                  obj.counter = index
                  obj.save()
                  index += 1


       Class myModel(model.Models):
              counter = models.IntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
```

Comment: Of course you can do it like this but this does not scale well if you have thousands of objects in your database. Then when you call `add_counter` it will need to update all rows in table. For that reason I did not suggest doing this.